# File is not updated when doing current append

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-lake

I am using an AdlsClient to send messages to an Azure Data Lake in parallel threads.
The problem is that the file that I'm writing to is only written to when it is created.

The file is only updated when I manually read it and then refreshes the directory.

I have, in a lab project, tried to log the size of the file after each write and it is not changed after the first write which also creates the file.

What is causing this behavior? Is it normal or may I be using it incorrectly?

**UPDATE:**
This is the code snippet where I call append.

```
var datetime = DateTime.Now;
var fileName = $"/data/{datetime.Year}/{datetime.Month}/{datetime.Day}/{datetime.Hour}.txt";
var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

client.ConcurrentAppend(fileName, true, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
Console.WriteLine(client.GetDirectoryEntry(fileName).Length);
```

I write out the length of the file to check if the file has been appended after writing to it.

**UPDATE 2:**

After some more testing, I have realized that doing lots of concurrent appends actually *does* update the file. However the previous scenario is still valid when the appends stops. The most recent appends are not updated to the file until I manually read it.

So what I'm interested in is how the cache of appends work and what time frame they are hold in default before being written to the file.

Comment: Are you trying to make different threads write at the same time in a single file?
If yes, what might be happening is that the file is blocked by another thread, so you can not write

Comment: Please, share the code you are using to write into file

Comment: @CelsoLívero That is the goal, but I'm not doing it at the moment in my test. But that is what I understood ConcurrentAppend() was for, writing to a file from multiple sources.

Comment: @arghtype I have added the code snippet now.